# SQL Server service does not start by code

Tags: c#, sql-server, service

I need a service that run automatically start the SQL instances that are on the machine. So far so good, I can make all of them work, but when I run on a machine with Windows 7 I get an error 1053 (timeout). But changed the timeout to 180000 and the error continues.

I do the same process in Windows 10 and runs 100% on instances of SQL Express 2005, 2008 and 2012.

I can not be sure if the problem is actually Windows 7 or SQL Server 2005 that is in this windows 7 if I do the process manually start it starts normally.

Code:

```
public static bool StartServices()
{
    try
    {
        bool startedWithSuccess = false;
        foreach (var servico in GetInstances())
        {
            using (servico)
            {
                if (servico.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running
                    && servico.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
                {
                    servico.Start();

                    startedWithSuccess = TimeoutHelper.RetryUntilSuccessOrTimeout(() =>
                    {
                        servico.Refresh();
                        return servico.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running ? false : true;
                    }, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONS);
                }
                else
                {
                    startedWithSuccess = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return startedWithSuccess;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new SqlServerStartServiceException();
    }
}

public static ServiceController[] GetInstances()
{
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(x => x.ServiceName.Contains("SQL")).ToArray();
    var lista = services.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains("Agent") ||
                                        x.DisplayName.Contains("Browser") ||
                                        x.DisplayName.Contains("VSS") ||
                                        x.DisplayName.Contains("Active")).ToArray();
        return services.Except(lista).ToArray();
}
```

Using the **cmd** and *net start xxxx* command also works.

Comment: Does the user your running this service as have security rights to start and stop services?

Comment: how can I Execute services.msc with admin privileges? On Windows 10 this is not required? But Works on W10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem inserting dependencies in the service.

```
this.serviceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = SqlServerServiceHelper.GetInstances().Select(x => x.ServiceName).ToArray();


public static ServiceController[] GetInstances()
{
     ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(x => x.ServiceName.Contains("SQL")).ToArray();
     var servicesToRemove = services.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains("Agent") ||
                                           x.DisplayName.Contains("Browser") ||
                                           x.DisplayName.Contains("VSS") ||
                                           x.DisplayName.Contains("Active")).ToArray();
     return services.Except(servicesToRemove).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mcs will run as you user that's not the same thing as the user this service runs as. Navigate to the service right click> properties and change the user from local machine to one that has access. Try your user to see if that works than its a security issue. [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755249.aspx)

Comment: I will test this soon here about 2 hours. I am formatting the notebook and will install it again to see if it does not work, do what you said.

Comment: Run as administrator and had no effect.